# React Routing - How to Organize Redirect With OnClick In Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm really confused about where to place Routers, Routes, and Redirects/history.push in my code. When a button is clicked in my child component, the parent component's `onIndexChange()` method is called. (Because I'm required to use some previously built components, I can't use `Link`). I want the `onIndexChange(newIndex)` method to redirect the user based on the new index value. I have my `Router` and `Routes` defined in the parent component's `render` method. I don't understand how or where to insert a `Redirect` component/make a call to history.push so that the correct `Route` is called. What do I need to modify?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeIndex: 0,
        };
        this.onIndexChange = this.onIndexChange.bind(this);
    }

    onIndexChange(newIndex) {
        const profileType = this.state.profileType.toLowerCase();
        const routePath = `${profileType}/${newIndex}`;
        this.setState({activeIndex: newIndex});
        //this.context.router.push(routePath); ??
        //return <Redirect push to={routePath} />; ??
    }

render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <MemoryRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header onIndexChange={this.onIndexChange} />
                    <Route exact path="/standard/0" render = { (props) => <StandardOverview {...props} {..overviewProps}/> } />
                    <Route exact path="/standard/1" render = { (props) => <StandardActivity {...props}{...activityProps} /> } />
                    <Route exact path="/special/0" render = { (props) => <SpecialOverview {...props}{...overviewProps} /> } />
                    <Route exact path="/special/1" render = { (props) => <SpecialInfo {...props} /> } />
                    </MemoryRouter>
                </div>
            </MemoryRouter>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Header.js (child)

```
render() {
  return <SpecialNavigation tabs={tabs} onClick={this.props.onIndexChange} />; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) api provided by `react-router` and leverage `withRouter` to create high order components for your `App` component, as well as any other components which need access to the history api. These higher order components will then be allowed to push to the browser's history.

Directly from the documentation:

"*You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders*"

Something along the lines of: (for `App.js`)

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
class App extends Component {
    ...
    onIndexChange(newIndex) {
        const profileType = this.state.profileType.toLowerCase();
        const routePath = `${profileType}/${newIndex}`;
        this.setState({activeIndex: newIndex});
        // assuming your newIndex correctly contains the new route
        this.props.history.push(newIndex);`
    }
    ...

};

export default withRouter(App);
```

**Note**: You can apply this technique to any component which needs access to the history api.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is so close! I was able to get the first component to render nicely (/standard/0). But when I clicked the next tab for /standard/1 and triggered the onIndexChange method, the StandardActivity component never got rendered. How does this.props.history.push(routePath) impact what route component gets rendered?

Comment: What was the value of your new route to be rendered, perhaps it was off? Additionally, verify your onIndexChange() method was fired again. As for your history question it will match based on your defined <Route> components. Checkout this link for more details: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md

Comment: My new route was off. Your solution worked and I marked it as the accepted answer! Thank you!